# Is it possible to take snapshot of existing HDInsight cluster in azure

Tags: azure-hdinsight

Currently we have a HDInsights cluster which we might have to shut it down or delete for few days. We need the cluster in the same state as we left. What are the ways we can preserve the current snapshot of this cluster and restore it back after few days.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how have you created the HDInsight cluster. When you created the cluster, did you specify external meta stores, so that your hive meta store is running on your own SQL azure and not the one that HDInsight created?

Check this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-provision-linux-clusters#use-hiveoozie-metastore

If you haven't used external meta stores when you created the cluster, unfortunately, you will lose that state. Your data however, will be persisted in the Azure blob store or Azure data lake store.

Comment: answer shouldn't contain question - that's what comments are for. you should elaborate better on how to fix a problem and quote important parts of documentation, not the whole documentation page as na answer